# Where is variable data stored in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

While I know that the memory layout is supposed to be :

**Text Segment** : Executable instructions(I am guessing machine code in binary)

**Initialised Data Segment** : Global and static variables that are initialised,
if static int a = 10; a is stored here and I am assuming the value 10 is also stored here?

**Uninitialised Data Segment** : Stores uninitialised variables. static int a; ‘a’ will be stored here.

**Stack** : Local, temporary variables, recursive function calls, return address.

**Heap** : Dynamic memory allocated to a variable through malloc or realloc.

```
char *s = “hello world”
```

Where will the pointer variable and the string “hello world” be stored?

Comment: `char *s = “hello world”` is invalid in C++. It should be `const char* s = "hello world;"`.

Comment: standard doesn't define memory layout. This is compiler platform specific stuff.

Comment: Where is `s` being declared? I think most of this isn't specified by the c++ standard and is up to implementations

Comment: Isn’t it const by default?

Comment: It could be anywhere according to context.

Comment: What about the data for a local variable pointer? Where would that be stored?

Comment: Is there an actual problem to be solved?

Comment: @the_minimalist Unfortunately nothing in C++ is `const` by default (though many of us wish that was not the case)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: what ?? For instance, `char *s = "hello world"; s= 0;` is perfectly valid, and can make sense.

Comment: @the_minimalist The data for a local variable pointer is stored in an implementation-defined location. On common, consumer-grade hardware being produced today, it is a register, or it may spill onto the stack if there is register pressure and/or the address of the variable is to be taken. Your program gains nothing from knowing this, and if you somehow write code that assumes that local variables live on the stack, all you're doing is making your code less portable, more brittle, and more confusing for a reader.

Comment: The text literal is constant data, so it goes in the section where read-only data goes.  The `char` pointer *variable* is a variable and treated like any other variable, it goes: 1) registers? 2) stack? 3) Heap? 4) Global variable area?  All depends on a lot of declaration factors.  There is a possibility the pointer variable may not exist and the compiler emits code to access the text directly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, it's actually invalid in standard C++ while valid in standard C.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: my compiler does not care. Is that UB ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Since C++11 a compliant implementation should not even compile the program. Prior to C++11 you could declare a non-`const` `char*` to a string literal but actually changing the string literal would be UB if I remember correctly. If you use C++11 or later, and it still compiles, it may be an extension and if it has defined behavior it should be in the implementation's documentation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews By read-only memory, are you referring to the text/code segment(which contains machine code)?

Comment: @the_minimalist:  Depends on the executable format.  Some formats have sections for read-only data *and* the executable.  This allows for platforms to place the executable in one place (let's say MRAM) and the read-only data in Flash.  Again, the C++ language specification leaves the memory layout and purposes up to the platform.

Answer (score 4):

> Where is variable data stored in C/C++?

Depends on implementation. Here are some possibilities in general:

- In memory
- In a CPU register
- Nowhere

---

> While I know that the memory layout is supposed to be ...

What you describe may be true of some system / CPU architecture. It is not something specified in the C++ language.

---

> ```
> char *s = “hello world”
> ```
>
> Where will the pointer variable ...  be stored?

Given that the variable has static storage, and it is initialised, if your description is correct, then this applies:

> Initialised Data Segment : Global and static variables that are initialised

---

> Where will ... the string “hello world” be stored?

The string literal has static storage and it is initialised. It is not a variable though. None of the descriptions quite fit.

---

Also, the snippet is ill-formed (since C++11) because string literal is not convertible to pointer to non-const char.

Comment: and doing something like `s[2] = 3;` will compile but lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarekR In C++ that is. Luckily, the variable initialisation itself is ill-formed since C++11.

Comment: Let’s assume that s is a global/static variable, Is the string literal “hello world” stored in the text segment or the initialised data segment?

Comment: @the_minimalist Your description says that executable instructions are stored in text segment. You don't mention string literals being stored there.

Comment: @eerorika Text segment is the read only segment and I was wondering if in addition to storing executable instructions, it also stores literals

Comment: @the_minimalist Maybe. What did the documentation of the language implementation say?